# Using ajax promise with $.when().done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need two return values from two different ajax calling.

I have two javascript functions  :

```
this.getVal1= function(numberDep){
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url:url, //REST url
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    return promise;
};

this.getVal2= function(){
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url:url, //another REST url
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    return promise;
};
```

How I call these two functions :

```
 $.when(getVal1(17),getVal2())
 .done(function(_topdep,_alldep){
       console.log(_topdep);
       console.log(_alldep);

 });
```

Here are the result of each `console.log` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHBQx.png.

What I supposed to return from first `console.log` is those 17 records, and the second `console.log` is 36 records (please have a look in the above image) .

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you..

Comment: JQuery promise implementation is broken. You probably want to use a good promise library like RSVP and wrap the `$.ajax` calls in `RSVP.Promise` thereby using promises as they're intended to.

Comment: @Hrishi it's not _that_ broken!  This should be perfectly possible in jQuery.

Comment: @Hrishi Don't put up statements like that without backing them up with evidence. What you did there is pointless ranting.

Comment: @Alnitak It may be possible, but I was just suggesting OP use a fully spec compliant promise implementation.

Comment: @Hrishi in which case a shim for ES6 Promises would be more use than a third-party implementation...

Comment: p.s. the temporary `var promise` is unnecessary in this case - I would just write `return $.ajax(...)`

Comment: ...not only that, the entire `.ajax()` call in the example is full of superfluous mentions of defaults, likely it could be collapsed into a `.get()` one-liner, possibly making the entire wrapping function obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those are ajax promises and the ajax promises have more than 1 callback param(data, status, jqXHR) the `then` callback will receive an array as the value for each callback. So to get the data you need to get the first member of each argument

```
$.when(getVal1(17), getVal2())
.done(function (_topdep, _alldep) {
    console.log( _topdep[0] );
    console.log( _alldep[0] );

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rdenvmps/)

Comment: that second callback parameter isn't legal.

Comment: @Alnitak sorry... which parameter?

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing you want to return the results of the two separate ajax calls after both finish? If that's the case, then you could wrap each ajax request in a `Promise` and use the `Promise.all([promise1, promise2])` construct.

Comment: This is not necessary at all.  jQuery can solve this just fine without bringing in a new promise library.  There are legit reasons to bring in another promise library - this is not one of them.

Comment: jQuery's `.when()` does just that. Read [the spec](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: The answer does not ask the OP to use a particular promise library. It just suggests a possible implementation to solve OP's problem.